# Open source script for generating math exercises for elementary school students

Tags: open-source, math, educational

I am looking for a script generating exercises for elementary school students (=simple math task, more complicated than adding two numbers but less complicated than solving quadratic equations).

I am looking for an open source script as it is basically certain that I will want to change/expand/modify it.

Answer (score 1):

I found https://github.com/thearn/examgen that is a bit limited and producing tasks too complicated for elementary school.

But it may be a decent starting point if someone is plan to implement it on their own.

Comment: There are quite a few on github. You'll need to narrow search https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=maths+generator&s=stars&type=Repositories e.g. https://github.com/martinhammer/MathsGenerator